# django unicode url

Tags: django, dreamhost

**on deployment (Django + Dreamhost + passenger_wsgi)**

in my urls.py:

```
url(ur'^(?P<url>.+)/$', 'alp.news.views.blog_dispatcher', name='blog_dispatcher'),
```

the link:

```
domain.name/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B02/
```

leads to (looks like redirection):

```
domain.name/%25d0%2598%25d0%25bd%25d1%2584%25d0%25b02/
```

so, the "url" variable in my view = "%25d0%2598%25d0%25bd%25d1%2584%25d0%25b02"

**locally (or using dev server)**

When I use runserver command, even on deployment, it works well.
Ofcourse I could use urllib and unquote the url in my view, but the string in url still transforming '%' -> '%25'.
Have no idea, where does the magic begin: in passenger or wsgi app
May be someone could clear up ...

Answer (score 0):

the magic was in dreamhost's 301 redirection, which double-quoted the path